# Add a line to distinguish the Dismiss button on the New Question panel in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

At the current, the Dismiss button is at the same line with the text. Even it is bigger and in blue, I still mistakenly read the line as "On the navigation Dismiss".

[image]

I think adding a simple line is an easy solution for this:

[image]

You can draw it better.

Comment: I guess the downvotes may be because no one else reads that as "navigation dismiss". (i.e. they find the line completely redundant)

Comment: Do you agree with that?

Comment: Agree with what?

Comment: @TIPS agree with the redundancy?

Comment: Yes. Also now that it's being implemented, I hope the line doesn't look that bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will Dismiss be fixed in 1.5.3.3.

Comment: Yesterday when the update hadn't been released, I saw that the three lines of the text was reduced to two. I has dismissed it so I can't see it anymore, but is that simply because of the orientation of the iPad?